# yii2 join ->with() record right table data to the model

Tags: mysql, join, activerecord, yii2

A question about the relations in the project. Here is what I got:
I have a main table {{%page}} with a model Page working with it. It contains all the data for future dynamic usage in the views. 
Also i have a table {{%file}}, that contains the files for the particular Page. The key is the column 'builder_id'. I have created the relations between the models - in 'Page'

```
 `public function getFiles() {
        return $this->hasMany(File::className(),['builder_id' => 'builder_id']);  

    }`
```

and in 'File'

```
public function getPage() {
        return $this->hasOne(Page::className(), ['builder_id' => 'builder_id']);

    }
```

Goal: when getting the Page model using this method:

```
public static function getPageById ($builder_id = 1) {
        $model = Page::find()->where(['builder_id' => $builder_id])->one();

        if ($model === null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Error.");
        }

        return $model;
    }
```

to record into the model also the files for the page, where builder_id is the same. For this i am using `->with()`, that makes the Page mothod as follows:

```
public static function getPageById ($builder_id = 1) {
        $model = Page::find()
                ->with('file')
                ->where(['builder_id' => $builder_id]);

        if ($model === null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Error.");
        }
```

But in the model I get neither 1st table data, nor 2nd. Vardump of the model gives this

```
object(yii\db\ActiveQuery)#64 (27) { ["sql"]=> NULL ["on"]=> NULL ["joinWith"]=> NULL ["select"]=> NULL ["selectOption"]=> NULL ["distinct"]=> NULL ["from"]=> NULL ["groupBy"]=> NULL ["join"]=> NULL ["having"]=> NULL ["union"]=> NULL ["params"]=> array(0) { } ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["where"]=> array(1) { ["builder_id"]=> string(1) "2" } ["limit"]=> NULL ["offset"]=> NULL ["orderBy"]=> NULL ["indexBy"]=> NULL ["modelClass"]=> string(15) "app\models\Page" ["with"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "files" } ["asArray"]=> NULL ["multiple"]=> NULL ["primaryModel"]=> NULL ["link"]=> NULL ["via"]=> NULL ["inverseOf"]=> NULL }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to call `one()` or `all()` after query.

```
public static function getPageById ($builder_id = 1) {
    $model = Page::find()
            ->with('files') // here is you typo. You defined relationship with files and accessing it through file.
            ->where(['builder_id' => $builder_id])
            ->one(); // this line will return result.

    if ($model === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Error.");
    }
```

In your case, you didn't do anything with `ActiveQuery` object. **You need to call all() or one() on query object to get the result(s)**

Comment: i have already tried adding `->one()` and that caused this error: 
`app\models\Page has no relation named "file".`

Comment: It clearly says what you need. You need to define `getFile()` relation in `app\models\Page` class.

Comment: Please make sure that you write `with('files')` instead. I think you've defined relation like this: 

`public function getFiles() {
        return $this->hasMany(File::className(),['builder_id' => 'builder_id']);  

    }`

Comment: The point was right there - i tried with('file') instead of 'files', also i tried to make the relation based on a simple key, not a foreign one. To get that i had to re-generate the models.The mistype (or sooner misunderstood) letter cost me almost the whole day :) Thanks !